# How to intercept and give a fake response for HttpClient POST call with Angular and WebdriverIO for E2E testing

Tags: angular, webdriver-io

I'm testing out both Cypress and WebdriverIO to see E2E testing for an Angular app.

With Cypress I was able to intercept and give a fake response for the tests. But with WebdriverIO I am unable to do so, I followed the documentation on their website but the method they give you doesn't seem to work.

How to intercept an HTTP POST to an API and give a fake response?
My current test is this:

```js
it('Should click on the submit button and receive a response', async () => {
    const submitButton = await $('.mat-button-wrapper');

    // zou moeten werken maar doet niks ??

    let mock = await browser.mock('UrlForBackEnd', {
        method: 'POST'
    })

    mock.respond([{
        successfull: true,
         qrcode: 'MyUrlResponse',
          errorDescription: null
    }]);

    //test werkt enkel met echte backend.
    await submitButton.click();
    await browser.debug();
});
```

Comment: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/mock/ notes that Chrome Dev Tools protocol is required - is that available in your environment? What happens when you run the test? Also I'd say that if you're mocking out the request that's _not_ really an E2E test.

Comment: It's available. basically the test does nothing to intercept the actual post it just posts the supplied values to the actual backend API. So when the backend is running it will post a real post and give back a real QRcode so the customer can Pay. But for what i am doing i need to fake a response because i can't be posting real payment requests to the backend it's just supposed to be a test to show how the frontend handles incoming data.